DAX CALCULATETABLE/SUMMARIZE filter
I am struggling to add a filter to this DAX CALCULATETABLE/SUMMARIZE code in POWER BI. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

Function SUMMARIZE expects a column name as argument number 6

I have tried different filters with no luck as I keep getting the same error.
StudentAbsenceXXXX = CALCULATETABLE (
            SUMMARIZE (
                'Attendance2425',
                'Attendance2425'[AdmissionNo],
                'Students'[Year Group(s)],
                "Student Sessions Present",
                    CALCULATE (COUNTROWS ( 'Attendance2425' ),'Attendance2425'[Mark Meaning] = "Present" || 'Attendance2425'[Mark Meaning] = "Educational Activity"),
            FILTER(
                'Attendance2425',
                'Attendance2425'[Mark Meaning] = "Educational Activity"
            )
        ))

Ideally I would like to apply a filter from a related table 'Students' using the field 'Students'[Year Group(s)] but tried something simpler to try and correct the first error.

Try to use a variable for your measure :
StudentAbsenceXXXX = 
VAR SessionsPresent = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('Attendance2425'),
        'Attendance2425'[Mark Meaning] = "Present" || 
        'Attendance2425'[Mark Meaning] = "Educational Activity"
    )

RETURN
CALCULATETABLE(
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Attendance2425',
        'Attendance2425'[AdmissionNo],
        'Students'[Year Group(s)],
        "Student Sessions Present", SessionsPresent
    ),
    FILTER(
        'Attendance2425',
        'Attendance2425'[Mark Meaning] = "Educational Activity"
    )
)

